# CSS3 2x URL's background and one with opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I have this line:

```css
   background: url("../img/background-first-layer.png") no-repeat, url("../img/background-second-layer.png") no-repeat;
```

I need to add "opacity:0.15" but only for second layer - first layer is unchanged, maybe somebody know how to write it? ( I want to write it in one class)

### Edit Here you have example code:

```css
<body>
<div class="container">
        <header class="header-block" alt="code which dont want opacity">
            <a class="brand"><img src="/img/brand.png" alt="code which dont want opacity"></a>
            <a class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="code which dont want opacity"></a>
        </header>
        <div class="left-area" alt="code which dont want opacity">
        <p>code which dont want opacity</p>
            <section class="register-box" alt="code which dont want opacity">
              <p>code which dont want opacity</p>
              </section>
              
            
        
              
              </div>
              </body>
```

```html
body {
    color: #fff;
    background: url("../img/background-first-layer.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
     background: url("../img/background-second-layer.png") no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
    max-width: 2560px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}

.left-area {
    padding: 55px 0 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.brand {
    padding-right: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 112px;
    opacity: 0.42;
}
```

Comment: You would need to use 2 containers(or a pseudo element) with background image on each, and give one of them the opacity you want. As far as I know you cannot achieve this with only element, unless it is a background colour. If you can't change the html, then I would say use a pseudo element for one of the backgrounds and add opacity to it

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well, when I use opacity, other containers in this container also get opacity how to make it only for background(main container)?

Comment: When you do this with pseudo element and put the opacity on the pseudo element, you won't have that problem. Assuming your pseudo element does not have content. The point is, your content should be in the container that does not have opacity. If you post a simple code to reproduce your issue, I can post an answer

Comment: I added example code for first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a pseudo element. The pseudo element (::before) is placed absolutely inside of your original container and has the background image with z-index set to -1 and opacity set to 0.42. This way your content is not affected by the opacity and is above it so user can interact with it.

Now you can achieve this with another div inside of your original div as well (simply place a empty div/span and give it the same style as the pseudo element minus the `content: " "`) but I wasn't sure if you can or cannot edit the html

I added background colour so you can clearly see what's going on

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: green url("../img/background-first-layer.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-width: 2560px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.container::before {
  background: gray url("../img/background-second-layer.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.42;
  z-index: -1;
}

.left-area {
  padding: 55px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.brand {
  padding-right: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 112px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header-block" alt="code which dont want opacity">
    <a class="brand"><img src="/img/brand.png" alt="code which dont want opacity"></a>
    <a class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="code which dont want opacity"></a>
  </header>
  <div class="left-area" alt="code which dont want opacity">
    <p>code which dont want opacity</p>
    <section class="register-box" alt="code which dont want opacity">
      <p>code which dont want opacity</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```